# printf %p return value

Tags: c, printf

When I print a memory address with `printf %p` I get address in `hexdecimal` - something like `0x7ffee35f5498`. I am wondering why the `printf` return value is `16` and not the actual length of string, in this case `14`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(void)
{
char    *s = "Hello World!";
int x;

x = printf("%p\n", (void*)&s);
printf("%d\n", x);
return (0);
}
```

> output:
>
> 0x7ffeea6a3790
>
> 16

Address has 14 char but the function returned 16.

Documentation say's:

> printf() : It returns total number of Characters Printed, Or negative
>   value if an output error or an encoding error. ...

Comment: Are there spaces or newlines? Show the actual function call at least.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://onlinegdb.com/S1TP8JOpH).

Comment: The newline is counted too, so that should be 15.  Not sure about the other byte.

Comment: Your code prints `15` [here](https://www.ideone.com/ujUsbq), not `16`. What is your platform, compiler, ide etc. How do you compile and run the program? The actual length of the string is 14 + 1 = `15`, +1 because of the `\n` which of course counts also as a character. Is the code you're running _actually_ the code you posted in the question?

Comment: I bet it's a Windows compiler and it's also counting a \r by mistake.

Comment: @user253751 good point, but at least on my Visual Studio 2019 installation, the `\r` is not counted and the output is correct.

Comment: BTW: what output do you get if you replace `"%p\n"` with `"123"`?

Comment: I'm on Mac. You are right the output is 15 not 16. Now i got it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the same output 15.

Comment: "the actual length of string, in this case 14?" No it is 15. `"0x7ffeea6a3790\n"`.  The output is 16 characters as `"\n"` is certainly translated to `"\r\n"` - _on your platform if it is windows based_.

Comment: @lounchy so you can't get `16` with `"123"`, you should get 3. There is something really wrong with your question. Are you sure the code you __run__ is the code you __show__ here??

Comment: @Jabberwocky if I do `printf("123");` output = 3, if `printf("%p\n", (void*)&s);` where s = "123", output = 15. Now I understand why.

Comment: @lounchy So I hope you understood that `%p` just prints the _address_ regardless of the memory content at that address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not just printing the address but also a newline after it.  On Linux / MacOS systems a newline is one character (0xA) while on Windows systems it is two characters (0xD 0xA).

From your comments, you say you got 15 as your output and that you're on MacOS.  So that's 14 for the printed address plus 1 for the newline which is the expected result.